# How can I show a message with Toast class using the @JavascriptInterface?

Tags: android

I want get and display the text from server in the `WebView` environment and also with getting the message in the `WebView` I want show the same message using the `Toast` class. I wrote the following code But it does not display the text with `Toast` class.

```
<?php

echo "Hello";

?>
```

**And**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //WebView Object
        WebView browser;
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Enable Javascript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Inject WebAppInterface methods into Web page by having Interface name 'Android'
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        //Load URL inside WebView
        String s = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/webview.php";

        browser.loadUrl(s);
    }
    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /**
         * Show Toast Message
         * @param toast
         */
      @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `Android.showToast("hello")`

**Android** is the name of your `Javascript Interface`. Then by using that you can call the `showToast()` Function

### EDIT

Call a JavaScript function

```
<script>
    function showMessage(msg) {
        Android.showToast(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I added the `Android.showToast("hello")` in the `php` file, I did not see even a change in application behavior. Are you sure you from this solution?

Comment: See my edit. I am sure it'l work. bcz its worked for me

Comment: Wrap entire toast code in try except and display the exception somewhere, it probably is throwing exception "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch it's views"